# (C#) columns "leaked" between datagridviews when changing between tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to implement an interface to handle a db using c# and windows forms in visual studio and run into a problem I cannot solve. I have created a form containing a tabControl and two tabs, each of which has a combobox that lets the user choose a simple variable that is applied to a select query. The results from select are to be shown in the datagridview. Now, the select statements I am sure are correct because I have tried to execute with each of them separately so I'm thinking the problem is in my implementation of the datagridviews. What happens is when I first execute, the result in the first tab is correct but when I click on the second tab that contains datagridview2 it shows columns that are only supposed to be shown in the first one and are not present in the second select statement. What's even weirder is when I go back to the first tab the same thing happens with the columns of datagridview1. Here is how my code looks like

```
private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string ConStr = "myConnectionString";
   MySqlConnection DBCon = new MySqlConnection(conStr);

   string query = "SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM table1, table2 WHERE field1 = " + comboBox1.Text + ";";
   MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, DBCon);

   if (ds != null)
   {
      ds.Clear();
   }

   da.Fill(ds);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
   dataGridView1.Columns[field1].HeaderText = "FIELD1";
   dataGridView1.Columns[field2].HeaderText = "FIELD2";
   dataGridView1.Columns[field3].HeaderText = "FIELD3";
   dataGridView1.Columns[field4].HeaderText = "FIELD4";

   if (DBCon != null)
   {
      DBCon.Close()
    }

}

private void combobox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string ConStr = "myConnectionString";
   MySqlConnection DBCon = new MySqlConnection(conStr);

   string query = "SELECT field1, field4, field5 FROM table1 WHERE field1 = " + comboBox2.Text + ";";
   MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, DBCon);

   if (ds != null)
   {
      ds.Clear();
   }

   da.Fill(ds);
   dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
   dataGridView2.Columns[field1].HeaderText = "FIELD1";
   dataGridView2.Columns[field4].HeaderText = "FIELD4";
   dataGridView2.Columns[field5].HeaderText = "FIELD5";

   if (DBCon != null)
   {
      DBCon.Close()
    }

}
```

Now when I execute, at first dataGridview1 in tab1 contains the correct columns listed above but when I click on tab2 dataGridView2 shows FIELD3 and FIELD4 and when I click back on tab1 dataGridView1 also shows FIELD5;
Could you please point me to some direction so I can solve this problem cause I'm fairly new with c# and windows forms.
Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post

Comment: Use a local declared DataSet variable and ditch away the global one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a shared (common) `DataSet` and `DataTable` between the two.

Note that [DataSet.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) does not remove the existing tables from the data set, but according to the documentation

> Clears the DataSet of **any data** by removing all rows in all tables.

To solve the issue, don't use a shared data set. Remove the `ds` field and simply replace in both places

```
if (ds != null)
{
    ds.Clear();
}
```

with

```
var ds = new DataSet();
```